# Validation Rule Criteria Question

Tags: validation

I am trying to put a validation rule together that fires if certain values on the picklist field Presenting_Need_of_Case__c are populated and then requires the user to populate a contact field called "DV Perpetrator / Opposing Party". The following syntax is firing when Presenting_Need_of_Case__c picklist values are selected, but once I populate the "DV Perpetrator / Opposing Party" field, it still will not allow me to save. How do I add the "DV Perpetrator / Opposing Party" criteria to allow the user to save the record after that contact is added?

```
CASE
(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c, 
"Legal - Divorce", 1, 
"Counseling - Domestic Violence",1, 
"Immigration - UVisa/VAWA", 1, 
"Shelter - Domestic Violence", 1, 
"Legal - Divorce", 1, 
"Legal - Order of Protection", 1, 0) = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go ahead and give this a shot.

```
AND(    
CASE (
Presenting_Need_of_Case__c, 
  "Legal - Divorce", 1, 
  "Counseling - Domestic Violence",1, "Immigration - UVisa/VAWA", 1, 
  "Shelter - Domestic Violence", 1, "Legal - Divorce", 1, 
  "Legal - Order of Protection", 1, 0) = 1,
  ISBLANK(DV_Perpetrator_Opposing_Party__c))
```

I added some spacing just to make it look cleaner. Also, I guessed on the API name for the contact field. make sure you replace it with the actual API name for that field.

Comment: How does this compile? `AND` requires Boolean expressions, not numbers

Comment: That is a valid point that I didn't think of. I have update my answer.

Comment: No, you had it right before. You compare the `CASE` result to `1`. You can't output `TRUE`/`FALSE` from a `CASE` statement.

Comment: Alright, but isn't he right about AND not evaluating numbers?

Comment: You're not evaluating numbers. You're evaluating the `Boolean` output of the comparison `CASE(...) = 1`.

Comment: Gotcha, CASE is still a little confusing at times for me, because I don't use it that often. But I thought that it worked with AND.